# Make two input with same data value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two inputs(number).

How can I duplicate data from first to second and back?

For example, I'll set some value in first input and in second input I get same value and if I set same value in second input I want to get same value in first input.

I think it must be something like that

```
<div class="first">
    <input type="text" id="email">
</div>  
<div class="second">
    <input type="text" id="name">
</div>
<div id="slider"></div>

<script>
$('#email').change(function(){
    $(this).val($('#name').val());
});
('#name').change(function(){
    $(this).val($('#email').val());
});    
$('#slider').slider();
</script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Frunky/hzh9zwfo/4/

When I'm trying to put smth in slider() function I get error in console (slider function doesn't exist)

Thanks.

Comment: Show us what you've tried so far

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You almost had it...

Try this:

```js
$('#email').keyup(function (){
    $('#name').val($(this).val()); // <-- reverse your selectors here
});
$('#name').keyup(function (){
    $('#email').val($(this).val()); // <-- and here
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="first">
  <input type="text" id="email">
</div>  
<div class="second">
  <input type="text" id="name">
</div>
```

Comment: Also, what if I use one slide(jquery-ui) and one input(text or number)? Check my updated question please

Comment: That's a different question.  Suggest you post a separate question regarding your console log error.  It's likely that you didn't include the library required, but that's just a guess.

Answer (score 1):

Building on @technophobia 's answer, if you want them to update live, try this:

```
$('#email').keyup(function(){
    $('#name').val($(this).val());
});
$('#name').keyup(function(){
    $('#email').val($(this).val());
});
```