# tm extra product option select change woocommerce qty

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce, plugins

I'm trying to create a jquery that changes the woocommerce qty.
This is the resulting html.

```
  <div class="tc-cell tc-col">  <div class="tc-row"><div data-uniqid="5ecbf5c6c44cd8.41160631"
         data-logic=""
         data-haslogic=""
         data-fblabelshow=""
         data-fbvalueshow=""
         class="tc-container cpf_hide_element tc-cell tcwidth-100 cpf-type-radio centrado-div"
          id="impresion"><div class="tc-element-inner-wrap"><div class="tc-row">
    <label class="tc-cell tm-epo-element-label tcwidth-100">¿QUIERES IMPRIMIR TU BOLSA?</label>    <div class="tc-cell tc-col tm-extra-product-options-container">
    <ul data-rules="{&quot;Sin Impresi\u00f3n_0&quot;:[&quot;&quot;],&quot;Impresi\u00f3n a una cara_1&quot;:[&quot;&quot;],&quot;Dos caras mismo dise\u00f1o_2&quot;:[&quot;&quot;],&quot;Dos caras distinto dise\u00f1o_3&quot;:[&quot;&quot;]}"
        data-original-rules="{&quot;Sin Impresi\u00f3n_0&quot;:[&quot;&quot;],&quot;Impresi\u00f3n a una cara_1&quot;:[&quot;&quot;],&quot;Dos caras mismo dise\u00f1o_2&quot;:[&quot;&quot;],&quot;Dos caras distinto dise\u00f1o_3&quot;:[&quot;&quot;]}"
        data-rulestype="{&quot;Sin Impresi\u00f3n_0&quot;:[&quot;&quot;],&quot;Impresi\u00f3n a una cara_1&quot;:[&quot;&quot;],&quot;Dos caras mismo dise\u00f1o_2&quot;:[&quot;&quot;],&quot;Dos caras distinto dise\u00f1o_3&quot;:[&quot;&quot;]}"
        data-tm-validation="[]"     class="tmcp-ul-wrap tmcp-elements tm-extra-product-options-radio tm-element-ul-radio element_0 use_images_container centrado-ul">
        <li class="tmcp-field-wrap tmhexcolorimage-li-nowh tm-per-row tc-mode-images">
            <label class="tm-epo-field-label" for="tmcp_choice_0_0_15ee8f96bb31c4">
                    <input class="tmcp-field centrado centrado tmhexcolor_0-0-15ee8f96bb31c4 tm-epo-field tmcp-radio use_images"
                   name="tmcp_radio_0"
                   data-price=""
                   data-rules="[&quot;&quot;]"
                   data-original-rules="[&quot;&quot;]"
                   data-rulestype="[&quot;&quot;]"
                   data-image=""
                   data-imagec=""
                   data-imagep=""
                   data-imagel=""
                   data-image-variations="[]"
                                           value="Sin Impresión_0"
                   id="tmcp_choice_0_0_15ee8f96bb31c4"
                   type="radio"  checked='checked' 
            />
            <span class="tc-label-wrap tmhexcolor_0-0-15ee8f96bb31c4"><img class="tmlazy round radio_image" alt="Sin Impresión" src=""  /><span class="tc-label radio-image-label">Sin Impresión</span></span>    </label>
        <span class="tc-price-wrap">
        <span class="price tc-price hidden">
        <span class="amount"> &euro;</span>
    </span>
```

I have created this function inside my child theme in wordpress but I do not see it making any changes to me.
Somebody can help me.

Thank you

```
function prueba($pid){
?><script type="text/javascript">
     (function($) {
    "use strict";
         jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#tmcp_choice_0_0_15ee8f96bb31c4').change(function(evt) {
        if( $(this).val() != "Sin Impresión_0" ){
            $args['input_value']    = 10000;
        }
    });
});</script>
<?php
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'prueba' );
```

Comment: Does browser console shows you any errors ?

Comment: The browser does not show any errors. Just no change is made on the item I want to change by selecting the item I want the change to launch on the amount of product in woocomerce

Answer (score 0):

try this [Make two input with same data value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42460948/make-two-input-with-same-data-value/)